# Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' with kotlin suspend function in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

spring-boot version : 2.2.6.RELEASE

kotlin version: 1.3.71

kotlin coroutine version: 1.3.5

I'm trying to used suspended function in a controller in spring boot. [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/languages.html#controllers) is the official doc that shows an example.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account/v1")
class UserAccountResourceV1 {
    @GetMapping("/username-taken", produces = [MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE])
    suspend fun userNameTaken(): String {
        return "yes"
    }
}
```

I've added required dependencies in build.gradle.kts:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    implementation(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx", name = "kotlinx-coroutines-core", version = "1.3.2")
}
```

It breaks in runtime throwing this err:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported suspending handler method detected: public java.lang.Object com.example.user.service.resources.UserAccountResourceV1.userNameTaken(kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)
```

complete stderr is [here](https://gist.github.com/abhisekpadhi/203720b34aac8d4a6f48b5f3fca8828f).

Need some help in figuring out what is wrong with my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the solution.

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
```

needed to be replaced with

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
```

Basically `spring-boot-starter-webflux` brings support for suspened functions.